# JFreeChart with XYBoxAnnotation Open on One Side

Tags: java, plot, charts, annotations, jfreechart

I'm using an [XYBoxAnnotation](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYBoxAnnotation.html) to demarcate a rectangular area on a JFreeChart. I would like one side of the box to be "open", i.e go out to infinity. I tried setting the value to `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` but this did not seem to work. I also tried setting it to `Double.MAX_VALUE`, with no luck either. In these cases, the annotation doesn't even show up on the plot at all. And there are no exceptions thrown.

Below is a very simple version of my code in which I generate the XYBoxAnnotation and add it to the plot.

```
XYBoxAnnotation _axisMarker = new XYBoxAnnotation(xLow, yLow, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, yHigh, new BasicStroke(0.5F), Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE);
_plot.getRenderer().addAnnotation(_axisMarker, Layer.BACKGROUND);
```

EDIT:

I figured out that the reason the annotation wasn't showing up was because the x value for the annotation was much much larger than the axis scale. For some reason, this causes the annotation to not be visible until you zoom out enough.

Thanks to @trashgod's answer below, I came up with a solution. His answer didn't quite work for me since my plot allows zooming and you could see the edge of the box when you zoomed out.

First, I added a `PlotChangeListener` to listen for when the plot is zoomed:

```
// define PlotChangeListener to update the annotation when the plot is zoomed
private PlotChangeListener _zoomListener = new PlotChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void plotChanged(PlotChangeEvent plotChangeEvent) {
    if (_basisIsotope != null) {
      updateAxisMarkers();
    }
  }
};
```

Then I created a function to re-draw the annotation based on the new plot bounds:

```
// function to re-draw the annotation
private void updateAxisMarkers() {
  _plot.removeChangeListener(_zoomListener); // remove to prevent triggering infinite loop

  // define xLow, yLow and yHigh...

  double xHigh = _plot.getDomainAxis().getUpperBound() * 1.1;
  XYBoxAnnotation _axisMarker = new = new XYBoxAnnotation(xLow, yLow, xHigh, yHigh, new BasicStroke(0.5F), Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE);
  _plot.getRenderer().addAnnotation(annotation);

  _plot.addChangeListener(_zoomListener); // add back
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double.MAX_VALUE` is too large to scale to the relevant axis, but `Double.MAX_VALUE / 2` works as well as any value larger than the upper bound of the axis. A better choice might be a value that exceeds the maximum value of the domain by some margin. The fragment below shades a plot of some Gaussian data with an `XYBoxAnnotation` that has domain bounds extending from 42 to the maximum domain value + 10%; the range bounds are ±1σ.

```
XYSeriesCollection dataset = createDataset();
JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
Color color = new Color(0, 0, 255, 63);
double max = dataset.getSeries(0).getMaxX() * 1.1;
XYBoxAnnotation annotation = new XYBoxAnnotation(
    42, -1, max, 1, new BasicStroke(1f), color, color);
chart.getXYPlot().getRenderer().addAnnotation(annotation);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It didn't quite work for me because my plot allows zooming out. When zoomed, you can see the edge of the box. However, it did lead me to my solution. I added a `PlotChangeListener` to listen for when the chart is zoomed and then reset the box bounds to the new plot bounds.