# Joining Bars within Waterfall chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am creating a `Waterfall Chart` as shown in the below image.

```
public class WaterfallDemo extends ApplicationFrame {
    public WaterfallDemo(String title) {
       super(title);
       JFreeChart chart = createWaterfallChart();
       ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
       setContentPane(chartPanel);
   }

    public static JFreeChart createWaterfallChart() {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createWaterfallChart("","","",createDataset(),PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,LEGEND_ON,TOOLTIP_ON,false);
        //Customize chart legend for waterfall chart only
        chart.removeLegend();
        LegendTitle legend = new LegendTitle(new LegendItemSource1());
        chart.addLegend(legend);
        //update chart styles, legend and properties
        updateProperties(chart, isHorizontalBar, isStackedBar);  
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        WaterfallDemo waterfallDemo = new WaterfallDemo("Waterfall Chart Demo");
        waterfallDemo.pack();
        waterfallDemo.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(waterfallDemo);
        waterfallDemo.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class LegendItemSource1 implements LegendItemSource {
    public LegendItemCollection getLegendItems() {
      LegendItemCollection legendList = new LegendItemCollection();
      LegendItem item1 = new LegendItem("Increase");
      LegendItem item2 = new LegendItem("Decrease");
      LegendItem item3 = new LegendItem("Total");
      legendList.add(item1);
      legendList.add(item2);
      legendList.add(item3);
      item1.setFillPaint(ChartDefaults.SERIES_COLOR[1]);
      item2.setFillPaint(ChartDefaults.SERIES_COLOR[3]);
      item3.setFillPaint(ChartDefaults.SERIES_COLOR[0]);
     return legendList;
  }
}
```

Waterfall Demo Output:

[image: Waterfall Demo]

How do I connect one bar within another using a line as shown below? I could only add space between the bars by invoking `setCategoryMargin(double)` of `CategoryAxis` but did not find any API that performs connecting of bars with lines.

Note: Below image was taken from another example which was generated using different charting framework.

[image: Expected Waterfall output]

Comment: Have you tried to add a line chart to the graph? You could set the line data to place the lines where you need them.

Comment: @MichaelMcKay I already tried implementing XYLine Chart to draw lines between bars but end up creating multiple chart instances which is not advisable in my use case. If the chart has 10+ bars then I would end up creating 10+ instances of line chart which is not suggested.

Comment: Maybe `CategoryLineAnnotation`?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to draw lines between bars for my use case above by using `CategoryLineAnnotation` as per @trashgod comment above.

Updated Code:

```
public class WaterfallDemo extends ApplicationFrame {
    public WaterfallDemo(String title) {
       super(title);
       JFreeChart chart = createWaterfallChart();
       ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
       setContentPane(chartPanel);
   }

    public static JFreeChart createWaterfallChart() {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createWaterfallChart("","","",createDataset(),PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,LEGEND_ON,TOOLTIP_ON,false);
        //Customize chart legend for waterfall chart only
        chart.removeLegend();
        LegendTitle legend = new LegendTitle(new LegendItemSource1());
        chart.addLegend(legend);
        //update chart styles, legend and properties
        updateProperties(chart, isHorizontalBar, isStackedBar);

        CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.addAnnotation(new CategoryLineAnnotation("GROUP A", 42.0, 
                "GROUP B", 42.0, Color.red, new BasicStroke(1.0f)));
        plot.addAnnotation(new CategoryLineAnnotation("GROUP B", 32.0, 
                "GROUP C", 32.0, Color.red, new BasicStroke(1.0f)));
        plot.addAnnotation(new CategoryLineAnnotation("GROUP C", 62.0, 
                "GROUP D", 62.0, Color.red, new BasicStroke(1.0f)));
        plot.addAnnotation(new CategoryLineAnnotation("GROUP D", 40.0, 
                "GROUP E", 40.0, Color.red, new BasicStroke(1.0f)));
        plot.addAnnotation(new CategoryLineAnnotation("GROUP E", 50.0, 
                "GROUP F", 50.0, Color.red, new BasicStroke(1.0f)));
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        WaterfallDemo waterfallDemo = new WaterfallDemo("Waterfall Chart Demo");
        waterfallDemo.pack();
        waterfallDemo.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(waterfallDemo);
        waterfallDemo.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class LegendItemSource1 implements LegendItemSource {
    public LegendItemCollection getLegendItems() {
      LegendItemCollection legendList = new LegendItemCollection();
      LegendItem item1 = new LegendItem("Increase");
      LegendItem item2 = new LegendItem("Decrease");
      LegendItem item3 = new LegendItem("Total");
      legendList.add(item1);
      legendList.add(item2);
      legendList.add(item3);
      item1.setFillPaint(ChartDefaults.SERIES_COLOR[1]);
      item2.setFillPaint(ChartDefaults.SERIES_COLOR[3]);
      item3.setFillPaint(ChartDefaults.SERIES_COLOR[0]);
     return legendList;
  }
}
```

Ouput:

[image: Waterfall Demo with connector lines]

Comment: For easier maintenance, derive the annotation bounds from the dataset, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44711540/230513).